# Cholmod error 'out of memory' : Merging Seurat Objects

Tags: r, merge, sparse-matrix, seurat

I am trying to merge Seurat class objects that contain transcriptome count data (sparse matrix).  I am relatively new to R, so any help/solutions is appreciated. I have added a screenshot of the data I'm working with.

```
**General Info:**
-------------

> memory.size(max = TRUE)
[1] 2533.94
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
[5] datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RSQLite_2.2.3 Seurat_3.2.3
```

I am not sure if my storage is the issue or if I should split the function in two.

```
 options(stringsAsFactors = F)
setwd("C:/Users/Amara/OneDrive - Virginia Tech/XieLab/ZebraFish_Project/zf_brain-master/data")
folders <- list.files("C:/Users/Amara/OneDrive - Virginia Tech/XieLab/ZebraFish_Project/zf_brain-master/data")
library(Seurat)
library(dplyr)
zfbrainList = lapply(folders,function(folder){ 
  CreateSeuratObject(counts = Read10X(folder), 
                     project = folder )
})
zfbrain.combined <- merge(zfbrainList[[1]], 
                 y = c(zfbrainList[[2]],zfbrainList[[3]],zfbrainList[[4]],zfbrainList[[5]],
                       zfbrainList[[6]],zfbrainList[[7]],zfbrainList[[8]],zfbrainList[[9]],
                       zfbrainList[[10]],zfbrainList[[11]],zfbrainList[[12]],zfbrainList[[13]],
                       zfbrainList[[14]],zfbrainList[[15]]), 
                 add.cell.ids = folders, 
                 project = "zebrafish")
```

Error in .cbind2Csp(x, y) :
Cholmod error 'out of memory' at file ../Core/cholmod_memory.c, line 147

[Data folder](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgDgtj_I4R0Dwi8HOJGwHxMXqFgv?e=TQE2c6)

[image: zfbrainlist]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The machine used to process the data in the original question has a 64-bit Windows operating system running a 32-bit version of R. The result from `memory.size()` shows that approximately 2.4Gb of RAM is available to the `malloc()` function used by R. The 32-bit version of R on Windows can access a maximum of slightly less than 4Gb of RAM when running on 64-bit Windows, per the [help for `memory.size()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/memory.size).

[image]

[Memory Limits in R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Memory-limits.html) tells us that in 32-bit R on Windows it is usually not possible to allocate a single vector of 2Gb in size due to the fact that windows consumes some memory in the middle of the 2 Gb address space.

[image]

Once we load the data from the question, the `zfbrainList` object consumes about 1.2Gb of RAM.

```
options(stringsAsFactors = F)
folders <- list.files("./data/zebraFishData",full.names = TRUE)
library(Seurat)
library(dplyr)
zfbrainList = lapply(folders,function(folder){ 
     CreateSeuratObject(counts = Read10X(folder), 
                        project = folder )
})
format(object.size(zfbrainList),units = "Gb")
```

...and the result:

```
> format(object.size(zfbrainList),units = "Gb")
[1] "1.2 Gb"
```

At this point, the code attempts to merge the objects from the list into a single object.

```
zfbrain.combined <- merge(zfbrainList[[1]], 
                          y = c(zfbrainList[[2]],zfbrainList[[3]],zfbrainList[[4]],zfbrainList[[5]],
                                zfbrainList[[6]],zfbrainList[[7]],zfbrainList[[8]],zfbrainList[[9]],
                                zfbrainList[[10]],zfbrainList[[11]],zfbrainList[[12]],zfbrainList[[13]],
                                zfbrainList[[14]],zfbrainList[[15]]), 
                          add.cell.ids = folders, 
                          project = "zebrafish")
```

When we calculate the size of the resulting `zfbrain.combined` object, we find that it is also about 1.2Gb in size, which exceeds the RAM available to R on the original poster's machine.

```
format(object.size(zfbrain.combined),units = "Gb")

> format(object.size(zfbrain.combined),units = "Gb")
[1] "1.2 Gb"
```

Since the `zfbrainList` must be in RAM while `zfbrain.combined` is being created, it is not possible to execute the merge as coded above in an instance of R that has only 2.4Gb of RAM accessible because the RAM consumed by both `zfbrainList` and `zfbrain.combined` is between 2.4 - 2.5Gb, exclusive of other RAM needed by R to run.

### Solution: use the 64-bit version of R

Since most Windows-based machines have at least 4Gb of RAM, and the amount of RAM reported by `memory.size()` was 2.4Gb, it's likely there is at least 4Gb of RAM on the machine.  The machine used in the original post already had 64-bit Windows installed, so we can enable R to access more memory by installing and running the 64-bit version of R.

On a Windows-based machine with 8Gb RAM, 32-bit R reports the following for `memory.size()` and `memory.limit()`.

[image]

Interestingly, R reports 25.25 for `memory.size()` because 1Mb is rounded down to 0.01 per the [help documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/memory.size), but `memory.limit()` provides a number between 0 and 4095 (also per the documentation). On our test machine it reports 3583, about 3.5Gb of RAM.

When we run these functions in 64-bit R on the same machine, `memory.size()` reports 34.25, which means that `malloc()` will allocate a single object as large as 3.3Gb, and `memory.limit()` reports that R can access a total of 8Gb of RAM, the total amount that is installed on this particular machine.

[image]

### Testing the solution

When I run the code in a 32-bit R 4.0.3 session on 64-bit Windows, I am able to replicate the out of memory error.

[image]

When I run the code in the 64-bit version of R, it runs to completion, and I am able to calculate the size of the resulting `zfbrain.combined` object.

[image]